# What are the reference document to installing WSO2 Private Pass in EC2

Tags: wso2, cloud, wso2-stratos

What are the reference document to installing WSO2 Private Pass in EC2. I didn't find any appropriate docs for this.

Answer (score 0):

At the core of WSO2 Private PaaS, lies Apache Stratos 4.00 (incubating) project, providing cloud-native capabilities such as multi-tenancy, elastic scaling, self-service provisioning, metering, billing and resource pooling among several other functionalities. WSO2 private pass bundled with Cartridges that use commonly.

Next release of private pass will include more easy options on setup. For now you can follow current stratos Cartridge guide on this..

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/STRATOS/4.0.0+Creating+a+Cartridge+on+EC2

Answer (score 0):

Follow this blog post, then you have to learn these techniques to add to your problem

[Deploying Apache Stratos 4.0.0 in 15 mins using EC2](http://blog.ravihansa3000.com/2014/07/deploying-apache-stratos-400-in-5mins.html)

Follow above article and will get a broad knowledge in WSO2 Private Pass in EC2. Hope this helps